# Typescript if condition with boolean not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement

There is something strange going on and I really don't know why.
In my angular project I have a component which has a child-component. The parent component's html is like this:

```
<child-component [isEditable]="isEditable"></child-component>
```

In parent component ts I declared the property "isEditable" :

```
isEditable: boolean = true;
```

and then in ngOnInit:

```
this.isEditable = false;
```

Then in child component I have the correspondent input property with default value:

```
@Input() isEditable: boolean = true;
```

When this value changes to false from the parent, I need to implement some logic. The problem is that both in ngOnInit and ngOnChanges of the child component, if I do

```
if(!this.isEditable) {
   console.log("DO SOMETHING");
}
```

It doesn't enter the condition. So I thought about some "delay" in receiving the new value, added a console.log before the if condition but it turned out it was correctly *false*.
I ended up doing this in ngOnInit method:

```
console.log("BEFORE IF", this.isEditable);
if(this.isEditable){
   console.log("ENTERED IN TRUE", this.isEditable);
}
```

and this is the output:

[image]

I really don't get what's wrong. The property is false as it should be but it enters the condition with true. I'm sure it's something stupid but I don't get it...

Comment: Is the change detection strategy of parent component `OnPush`?

Comment: No, I've left the default one, but how can it enter the if condition if it's false?

Comment: Ok. Can you try this in child component: `@Input() set isEditable(val){ console.log(val)}`

Comment: Can you try `console.log(typeof this.isEditable)`? Because this make it seems like it's a string `"false"` which is a trurthy value.

Comment: @VLAZ is right, your console is displaying a string there.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `isEditable="isEditable"` instead of `[isEditable]="isEditable"` ?

Comment: @VLAZ why is it a string if I've declared it in both component as a boolean? What happens?

Comment: @Maryannah no I've wrote it correctly

Comment: @Usr then please, provide a [mcve] of your issue and/or your full code so that we can find the error. Because clearly, your console log displays a string, and a stated, it behaves like the variable is a string.

Comment: @Usr you've declared it as a boolean but the type system only exists at compile time. If you've done something to the effect of `this.isEditable = userInput as boolean` then that forces the compiler to accept the value is a boolean *even when it won't be*. Since this passes compilation, at runtime you'd get this sort of behaviour - there are no type checks at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a setter on the input

```
  @Input() set isEditable(isEditable: boolean) {
    console.log('isEditable', isEditable);
  }
```

this code will run every time isEditable will change from the parent.

Also using `ngOnChanges` is a valid approach, but you will need to filter to the property you need. You can find an example in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges).

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` offers a parameter that you can use of type [`SimpleChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges).

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(changes.isEditable.currentValue);
}
```

Try using this variable instead of your input, see what happens.